# How to open an installed PWA as a firefox instance instead of a chrome instance?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, progressive-web-apps

Is there a place where I can configure an instance of which browser a PWA should use?

Comment: It is installed using the browser selected by the user viewing your website before the install. You have no option to override the user's desired browser.

Comment: I'd installed the PWA from Firefox, and the default browser is Chrome.
It always opens in Chrome

Comment: Not it should use what you installed with when you USE THE NEW ICON. 1. Desktop or Mobile? 2. Does your PWA when running with an HTTPS URL pass as a valid PWA with the Chrome Lighthouse tool? If there are issues, it usually gives good hints.